# How to populate dropdown from database using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having difficulty in displaying data from the database to drop-down i tried all but it just doesn't work.

I want it to look like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJxxJ.png) but i just can't seem to make it work.
 The user should be able to get the employee's id/name from the database.

I have tried this website but i don't know where to put everything, it's just so confusing. I need help. Thank you.

Here is my code:

**CONTROLLER** (home.php)

```
public function viewAddEmployeePayrollForm() { // input employee's payroll
        $this->load->view('imports/header');
        $this->load->view('imports/menu');
        $this->load->view('payroll/payroll_add');
    }

    public function saveEmployeePayroll() { // save the inputted details
        $this->load->model('Model_payroll');
        $p = new Model_payroll();
        $p['employees'] = $this->db->get('employees')->result();
        $p->emp_id = $this->input->post('empid');
        $p->basic_salary = $this->input->post('emp_salary');
        $result = $p->saveEmployeePayroll();
        if (!$result) {
            echo mysqli_error($result);
        }
        else {
            redirect('home/goViewEmpPayroll', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

**VIEW** (payroll_add.php) **this is how my view looks like** [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7H4V.png)

```
<h1>Add Employee Payroll</h1>
   <br>
   <?php echo form_open('home/saveEmpPayroll',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Select Employee</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
       <select class="form-control" id="emp_id">
          <option value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['emp_id'])) { 
                          echo $_POST ['$emp_id'];}?>"></option>
       </select>    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: I noticed you have your controller file name home.php if your using codeigniter 3 and above you will find will need to be Home.php

Answer (score 0):

NOT Getting your code exactly but if you want a `select` drop-down fetch from server you can do some thing like this:

Controller:

```
$data['options']=array('option1','option2','onptionN');//Your options   
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

View :

```
  <select name='' id=''>
   <?php
   foreach($options as $option)
   {
   echo'<option value="'.$option.'">'.$option.'</option>'; 
   }
   ?>
   </select>
```